# Search result is disappearing when I search from the search result in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I am designing a theme for a job aggregation website (currently I am using default one which is twenty fourteen).

I am facing a problem is that when I search from a category page with proper keywords I get the result. and from the search result page I again search using a term not in the data base it shows nothing found.

Till this everything properly happening. But if I search once more using a keyword which is not in the data base it shows nothing found and change the category to null. So if I search again with proper keyword the result shows from other categories.

Here is the link to the website

http://alltopjobs.net/country/india

And here is the search.php code

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php
if ($_GET['cat'] != '') {
 $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=post'); // return only posts
} else {
 $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=page'); // return only posts
}
?>
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<form  method="get" id="jobsearch" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search any jobs here..." required value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?php echo $category[0]->cat_ID; ?>" />
 <button type="submit" id="jobsubmit" value="Search Jobs" />FIND JOBS</button>
</form>

 <section id="primary" class="content-area">
  <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

   <header class="page-header">
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
   </header><!-- .page-header -->

    <?php
     // Start the Loop.
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

      /*
       * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
       * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
       * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
       */
      get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

     endwhile;
     // Previous/next post navigation.
     twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

    else :
     // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
     get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;
   ?>

  </div><!-- #content -->
 </section><!-- #primary -->
```

No idea how to solve this issue.
Any solution for this problem highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: consider add PHP tag its mostly PHP related more than wp

Comment: Thank you Tural. But do you know what code I should use to get the category stable inside the browser? I am quite beginner in  PHP